# flexible solution for storing multiple unit of measurement for products

Tags: database, database-design

I want to implement multi unit of measurement(uom) for products, where allow user to purchase in different uom.

I have table below

```
Products
ProductId | Name   | price | active | id_supplier
1         | Food   | 10.00 | 1      | 1

Units
UnitId | Name
1      | Pcs
2      | Box
3      | Carton

UnitConversion
ProductId | fromUnit   | factor | toUnit | type
1         | 1          | 1      | 1      | default uom
1         | 2          | 20     | 1      | selling uom 
1         | 3          | 40     | 1      | selling & packing uom
```

I want to store multiple unit for products and show in view for a product e.g
1 pcs = $20, 1 box = $100 .. so on.

Or should i make a uom group which consist of conversion of unit and assign to the product? Which one better?

Is there any flaws in my design or anything that I miss?

Comment: Question: Does each product have a unique conversion for each unit?  That is, would a different product have a different conversion for unit #1?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not all products having the same conversion rate, some yes some no. E.g. Item A and Item B selling in Box, but when convert to pcs, item A  = 10pcs and item B = 20pcs.

Comment: Then your current design is already more or less normalized.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so it is unnecessary to create a uom group by the supplier and just create the unit conversion one by one for each product would be sufficient enough right?

Comment: If the `type` column information could repeat, then maybe you could create a new table for it, otherwise your design looks good to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay, thanks for it.